# How do I print x number of integers per line and only display the odd numbers in those lines?

Tags: c#

So far I can display the correct amount of integers per line, but I need to show only the odd numbers in the sequence. This is what I have so far:
Edited code:

```
 for ( counter = 1; counter <= max; ++counter)
                    {
                       
                        if( counter % 2 != 0 )  
                        {    
                            Console.Write(counter+"");

                           int printcounter = counter;
                           
                     
                            if (printcounter % 4 == 0)
                                {
                                  Console.WriteLine();
                                  }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Write('\t');
                                }
                            printcounter++;
                           
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
```

The output I'm getting

1

3

5

7

9

The output I'm trying to get:

1    3    5   7

9   11  13  15

Comment: Well, you basically already have it and it looks like you may be over complicating things… you only need ONE (1) loop… the … `while (counter<=max)` … loop is unnecessary and only complicates things. Hint… you will need two counters… you “could” possibly use the `counter` variable to know if you need to start a new row, however I suggest you simply create a separate variable to keep track of how many numbers have been printed and should work with the `if (printCounter % 4== 0)`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Got rid of the while loop and added a second counter, like you suggested , but now it displays all the odd numbers in a single row I feel like I'm missing something and I cant tell what.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and ADD the updated code at the end of your current question?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the actual output you get and the output you're trying to get

Comment: Thanks for all the helps guys, it helped me figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `printCounter` variable BEFORE the loop so that it persists and correctly tracks the number of things you've printed:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) { 
    int max = 21;
    int printCounter = 0;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= max; counter++)
    {        
        if(counter % 2 != 0 )  
        {    
            Console.Write(counter + "\t");
            printCounter++;
            if (printCounter % 4 == 0)
            {
              Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it… try it like below…

```
int max = 100;
int printCount = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter <= max; ++counter) {
  if (counter % 2 != 0) {
    Console.Write(counter + " ");
    if (++printCount % 4 == 0) {
      Console.WriteLine("");
    }
  }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Note: the line…

```
if (++printCount % 4 == 0) {
```

is shorthand for ….

```
printCount++;
if (printCount % 4 == 0) {
```

You only want to increment `printCount` when you print a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that was the piece pf the puzzle I was missing